# Python Selenium sending varible output to element problem via .sendkeys

Tags: python, string, selenium, variables

When I send on Chrome a normal static string `usrname = 'usernamefoo'` to the signup form via `.sendkeys`, it works fine. But if I send the output of `usrname = rand_name_1 + rand_name_2 + rand_name_3` something strange happens, it presses the signup button. There is no code pointing to this element in the script. The same happens on any element that I pass the variable directly via .sendkeys, but not if it's a string. Is it because it sending direct input from a variable or could it be a bug? BTW the signup button is located at the very end of the web form.

***edit**

I think that it is sending a "return" after writing each variable from `usrname`

in console it shows :

- dog
- rabitt
- slap

as the output of `ursname`

how do I format the output of `ursname` without carriage returns? just in case that is the actual problem?

I'll add the construct of `usrname` code

```
rand_name_1 = random.choice(open('dognames.txt').readlines())
rand_name_2 = random.choice(open('randomshit.txt').readlines())
rand_name_3 = random.choice(open('Randomlovenames.txt').readlines())

usrname = rand_name_1 + rand_name_2 + rand_name_3
```

So I've come to the conclusion that it does have a /n in the variable output

I ran an unpack and returned this result

`['d', 'u', 'k', 'e', '\n', 's', 'u', 'm', '\n', 'b', 'r', 'e', 'a', 'k', '\n']`

if I work out how to take out the /n's than I'll post it here.

Comment: I think the problem might be that it is sending a "return" after each varible

Comment: Might want to put the code down also the html element used on.

Answer (score 0):

So it was the \n form the random lists causing the problem

I used

```
rand_name_1 = rand_name_1.strip('\n')
rand_name_2 = rand_name_2.strip('\n')
rand_name_3 = rand_name_3.strip('\n')
```

to strip out the carriage returns, there is probably a much simpler way of doing this but it works for me and that's fine for the time being